# Retrieving parent/child records (object containing list) from Azure Mobile Services using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have .net 4.5.2 test app playing about with Azure Mobile Services and I'm attempting to store data using the `TableController`. I have my data types as follows:

```
public class Run:EntityData
{
public int RunId { get; set; }
public DateTime? ActivityStarted { get; set; }
public DateTime? ActivityCompleted { get; set; }
public List<Lap> LapInformation { get; set; }

public Run()
{
    LapInformation = new List<Lap>();
}
```

}

```
public class Lap
{
    [Key]
    public int LapNumber { get; set; }
    public int CaloriesBurnt { get; set; }
    public double Distance {get; set;}
    //Some other basic fields in here
    public DateTime? LapActivityStarted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LapActivityCompleted { get; set; }

    public Lap()
    {
}
```

In my Startup class I call:

```
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    new MobileAppConfiguration()
        .UseDefaultConfiguration()
        .ApplyTo(config);
```

And in my MobileServiceContext class:

```
public class MobileServiceContext : DbContext
{
    private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString2";

    public MobileServiceContext() : base(connectionStringName)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Run> Runs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Lap> Laps { get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
        new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
            "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
}
```

}

In my controller then, I have:

```
[MobileAppController]
public class RunController: TableController<Run>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Run>(context, Request);
    }

    public IList<Run> GetAllRuns()
    {
        var runs = context.Runs.Include("LapInformation").ToList();
        return runs;
}

public SingleResult<Run> GetRun(string id)
{
    return Lookup(id);
}

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostRun(Run run)
{
    Run current = await InsertAsync(run);
    return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
}

public Task DeleteRun(string id)
{
    return DeleteAsync(id);
}
```

}

I can then `POST` a record in `fiddler` which responds with a `201` and the Location of the newly created Item. An Example of the data I'm posting is:

```
{RunId: 1234, LapInformation:[{LapNumber:1,Distance:0.8, LapActivityStarted: "2017-06-19T00:00:00", LapActivityCompleted: "2017-06-19T00:00:00", CaloriesBurnt: 12}]}
```

However, when I `GET` that object, I'm only getting the fields from Run, without the list of Detail records (Lap). Is there anything I have to configure in Entity Framework so that when I GET a Run record from the DB, it also gets and deserializes all associated detail records?

Hopefully that makes sense.

**EDIT**
Turns out that it is pulling back all the lap information, but when I return it to the client, that information is getting lost.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Comment: Thanks for following up @Bruce-MSFT. I ended up taking your advice re: "I prefer handling tables individually and handling relationship management on the mobile client manually. This causes more code on the mobile client but makes the server much simpler by avoiding most of the complexity of relationships.". Just handling the parents and children independently and moving on with life! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom EF query with `Include()` method instead of Lookup call preferably overload that takes function from `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

```
var runs = context.Runs.Include(r => r.LapInformation)
```

Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Hmmm...OK, so Include, using a string (thats the only signature I have for the include() method) brings back the data. However, its not getting returned to the client. Is this a serialization issue then?

Comment: @LDJ What is returned as a result? There should not be any issues on first thought.

Also you can use other `Include()` signatures using a `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you could also use the `$expand` parameter to expand your collections as follows:

```
GET /tables/Run$expand=LapInformation
```

Here is my sample, you could refer to it:

[image]

You could mark your action with a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` for automatically adding the `$expand` property to your query request as follows:

```
// GET tables/TodoItem
[ExpandProperty("Tags")]
public IQueryable<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
{
    return Query();
}
```

For more details, you could refer to adrian hall's book [chapter3 relationships](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/#1many-relationships).

> EDIT Turns out that it is pulling back all the lap information, but when I return it to the client, that information is getting lost.

I defined the following models in my mobile client:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

After execute the following pull operation, I could retrieve the tags as follows:

```
await todoTable.PullAsync("todoItems", todoTable.CreateQuery());
```

[image]

Note: The `Tags` data is read-only, you could only update the information in the `ToDoItem` table.

Additionally, as adrian hall mentioned in [Data Access and Offline Sync - The Domain Manager](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/domainmgr/):

> I prefer handling tables individually and handling relationship management on the mobile client manually. This causes more code on the mobile client but makes the server much simpler by avoiding most of the complexity of relationships.